# How can I create a table with multiple items?

Tags: tables, itemize, split

I am trying to create a table for my thesis. But it has many items. How can I do that? I would be better if it fit on one page. Also, how can I remove tha space of between the lines of the table to make it fit on the page?

Thank you!!

Below is the table that I'm trying to create:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us the code you have tried so far?

Comment: @Higor, any news? No one answer help you?

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of what can be done with the `\compress` macro (found on this site), which makes LaTeX believe we're at the beginning of a minipage, so that a list adds no vertical spacing, and a customised list with the `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption, tabularx}
\usepackage{enumitem, ragged2e}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering
\setlist[itemize]{font= \color{DeepSkyBlue}, wide, leftmargin=*, noitemsep, after=\vspace*{-\topsep}}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\caption{Summary of advantages and disadvantages of HEP configurations}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{15mm}|*{2}{>{\compress\RaggedRight\arraybackslash} X |}}
\hline
HEP con\-figuration & Advantages & Disadvantages \\
\hline
Turbo-electric
& \begin{itemize}
  \item Does not depend on ad\-van\-ces of energy storage technologies
\item High design freedom for pro\-pulsional-aircraft integration
\end{itemize}
& \begin{itemize}
  \item High weight and low efficiency
\item Gas turbine engine is sized for peak power conditions
\item Depends on advances in HTS maaterial technology
\end{itemize} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to put Advantages and Disadvantages centered vertically and horizontally? For horizontally, centering{...stuff) does the job.

Comment: @pzorba75: Load `multirow`  and `makecell` and use `\multirowcell{2}{Advantages/Disadvantages}` (the value `2` depends on the number of lines of the  left column head).

Answer (score 1):

an alternative (for missed op's mwe is used nice Bernard answer (+1)):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
    \setcellgapes{2pt}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
    \makeatother
    \newcolumntype{I}{ >{\RaggedRight\compress\itemize}X<{\enditemize}}
    \newcommand*{\mcl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l|}{#1}}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
    \caption{Parameter settings of the present study}
    \label{5.1}
    \makegapedcells
\setlist[itemize]{font=\color{DeepSkyBlue},
                  nosep,
                  leftmargin=*,
                  after=\vspace*{-\baselineskip}}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{16mm}|*{2}{I |}}
    \hline
HEP con\-figuration
    &   \mcl{Advantages}    &   \mcl{Disadvantages}        \\
    \hline
Turbo-electric
    &   \item Does not depend on advances of energy storage technologies
        \item High design freedom for propulsion-aircraft integration
        &   \item High weight and low efficiency
            \item Gas turbine engine is sized for peak power conditions
            \item Depends on advances in HTS material technology
            \\
    \hline
Turbo-electric
    &   \item Does not depend on advances of energy storage technologies
        \item High design freedom for propulsion-aircraft integration
        &   \item High weight and low efficiency
            \item Gas turbine engine is sized for peak power conditions
            \item Depends on advances in HTS material technology
            \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]